# Count unique values based on multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique, countif

Can someone give me some inspiration please? I've been working on a formula for hours now and think I'm so deep into it I'm over complicating something.

Trying to work out;

Unique Users
Per Service
Per Month

[image]

I have tried a million different formulas and cannot get the result I need.

This is the last formula I tried;

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(L15=Data!$B$2:$B$200,1/(COUNTIFS(Data!$B$2:$B$200,$L15,
Data!$J$2:$J$200,$A$14,Data!$C$2:$C$200,Data!$C$2:$C$200)),0)))
```

L15 was source name
B:B source data
A:14 month name
J:J - month data
C:C - user

| # | Source | Agent | Month |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Website | Michael Govender | Jan-23 |  |
| 2 | Twitter | Michael Govender | Feb-23 |  |
| 3 | Website | Alison Naidoo | Feb-23 |  |
| 4 | Twitter | Mathew Naidoo | Mar-23 |  |
| 5 | Twitter | Meagan Reddy | Jan-23 |  |
| 6 | Instagram | David Naidoo | Feb-23 |  |
| 7 | Website | Tyron Maduray | Mar-23 |  |
| 8 | Instagram | Clare Murtle | Jan-23 |  |
| 9 | Twitter | Hellen Pumpkin | Mar-23 |  |
| 10 | Facebook | Tyron Maduray | Feb-23 |  |
| 11 | Instagram | Elaine Harley | Feb-23 |  |
| 12 | Twitter | Michael Govender | Jan-23 |  |

Comment: What is your formula? Is there a reason you can't use remove Duplicates?

Comment: =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(L15=Data!$B$2:$B$200,1/(COUNTIFS(Data!$B$2:$B$200,$L15,Data!$J$2:$J$200,$A$14,Data!$C$2:$C$200,Data!$C$2:$C$200)),0))) - but its not working

Comment: [Create sample data with this spreadsheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) or use [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Screenshots are hard to wrangle.

Comment: And please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75676293/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: Since `ArrayFormula` is not a Excel function, please show the VBA code you are using to implement in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel, try this:

```
=Counta(Index(unique(Filter(C2:E$99999,C2:C$99999<>"")),,1))

or

=Counta(Index(unique(Filter(C:E,C:C<>"")),,1))-1
```

This should work for Google Sheets

```
=Counta(Index(unique(Filter(C2:E,C2:C<>"")),,1))
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry new to this site. Can see how that will give me unique user - but how is it unique user by source and defined date too? As in multiple criteria?

Comment: No problem, by first question-standards, it wasn't terrible. Assuming that worked, do you mind clicking accept?